# JS Regexp for shortname

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm so bad at regexp expressions..

I've tried different things and nothing worked. :(

I'm just trying to verify that the shortname of someone could be added as url of my website like mysite.com/shortname

To do so, I absolutely need to be sure that it doesn't contain spaces, accent, special chars... juste [a-z] in fact.

I've tried this, but in vain:

```
 function isShortValid(shortcode){
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^([a-z]?$)/i);
        return pattern.test(shortcode);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need capture groups. Just use this regular expression to test your strings.

```
/^[a-z]+$/i
```

The bigger question here is of course:

**Is it possible to input invalid short names into the system without getting a validation error on the input?**

Because if it is possible, then you will have to resort to some other regular expression that will strip out invalid characters of your liking and create a correct short name when creating URLs. That URL parameter should of course be just a dummy segment (similar to stackoverflow). It's always wise to use direct user IDs that aren't changable and can't have invalid values because they're generated by the system.

These two links work the same:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/75642/robert-koritnik
https://stackoverflow.com/users/75642

The first one has the name included, but it's a dummy human friendly URL segment that can change at any time. ID on the other hand will always stay the same.

### How to instantiate regular expressions

You can either instatiate a regular expression directly

```
var rx = /^[a-z]+$/i;
```

or by using a constructor

```
var rx = new RegExp("^[a-z]+$", "i");
```

Don't use slashes in constructor initialization unless they are part of the regular expression.

Comment: deleted my answer. this is the same

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't work, I had to remove the '/' et 'i' char in my code (see my answer). Regarding this, I just wanted to add a simple js verification in the register form. I do more accurate tests/validation after in my code. But I really need to use this shortcode in my urls as it, not the id behind it, it would be poorly user friendly.

Comment: @CoBaLt2760: I don't see any particular change between your RegExp and mine. At least not in the part with slashes and ignorecase switch. Anyway. I'm glad that you've finally made it working. The problem is you're defining regular expression in a wrong way. When using a constructor you have to provide a string. Let me add some of this to my answer.

Comment: Thx for your edit, great! I understand better now how it works ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the regex to

```
var pattern = new RegExp('/^[a-z]+$/i');
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked perfectly. I added some numeric char too

```
function isShortValid(shortcode){
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^[a-z_0-9]+$/i);
        return pattern.test(shortcode);
    }
```

EDIT: Thanks to all your comments and help, I used this one which is perfect! Thx again!

```
function isShortValid(shortcode){return /^\w+$/.test(shortcode);}
```

Comment: I suggest you simply remove the constructor part to get `var pattern = /^[a-z_0-9]+$/i;`

Comment: then you should be using: `/^\w+$/` and the whole function could be reduced to `return /^\w+$/.test(shortcode);`

Comment: Just FYI: `[a-z0-9_]` using ignore case is exact equivalent to `\w` hence @SilentGhost's comment. That's why he omitted the *ignore case* switch, because `\w` includes upper and lowercase letters which makes ignorecase irrelevant.

Comment: Thaks to all, it's perfect now!